# iptux Installation causing error

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I'm trying to install iptux in CentOS by using

```
yum install ip*
```

it causes the following error

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: samba4-winbind conflicts with samba-winbind-3.6.9-167.el6_5.x86_64
Error: samba4-common conflicts with samba-common-3.6.9-167.el6_5.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
libstdc++6-gcc47-32bit-4.7.3_20130411-5.4.x86_64 has installed conflicts libstdc++6-32bit: libstdc++6-gcc47-32bit-4.7.3_20130411-5.4.x86_64
```

How can this error be resolved?

Comment: Which repositories you have enabled? Is there a reason why you couldn't update samba-winbind and samba-common to samba4-winbind and samba4-common?

Comment: I don't which repository I'm using. how to know this?

Comment: I'm using yum repository

Comment: Peek into `/etc/yum.repos.d`. The repositories are defined in simple text files which should be quite understandable even if the format itself is something you're not familiar with. The point I'm trying to make with repositories is: if you have several repositories which provide same packages, this might lead to a situation you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're running

```
yum install ip*
```

to install `iptux`, rather than

```
yum install iptux
```

?

The first command will install *every* package beginning with `ip` - which, while it will almost definitely include `iptux`, will also include many many other packages you probably do not want - presumably somewhere inside that glob are packages with conflicting dependencies, hence the error.

The second will install `iptux` and its dependencies.

Comment: if you try `yum install iptux` it showing some error  `No package iptux available.
Error: Nothing to do
`

Comment: Ah, ok. We'll need to know which version of CentOS you're running - `cat /etc/redhat-release` will tell you. Most likely the `yum` repositories you have configured - the collections of software you can install packages from - simply do not have `iptux` available, but you should be able to add a repo. that does :)

Comment: Scratch previous comment - it looks like there are no `iptux` packages for CentOS. You'll have to [build it from source](https://github.com/iptux-src/iptux), sorry.

Comment: how to install iptux please let me know.